# Checking an item from a livewire list automatically convert model into an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I was trying to implement selecting multiple items from a list by checking a checkbox but whenever I try to check an item its being converted into an array. I can convert my blade file to use the item as an array but the problem is the polymorphic relationship is not included in the item array. Can someone help me understand why its being converted in array after checking the checkbox?

```
public array $selectedItems = [];

@foreach($items as $item)
    <div class="w-full flex gap-4 items-center p-4">
         <input type="checkbox" wire:model="selectedItems" value="{{ $item->id }}">
         <p>{{ $item->product->name }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: add ```$items```, this information is not enough

Comment: How are you loading in `$items`? Livewire only hydrates a few sets of data, as can be read [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#important-notes). If it's not an `(Eloquent) Collection`, it won't properly re-hydrate the values after a component update.